# How to pick only one data from set of data from file.ts in other file while i am using jasmine data provider

Tags: visual-studio-code, protractor

I have a file which is Data.ts

```
export const hardshipTestData = 
{  
scenarios: 
    { CorrectCreds: { username: 'xyz', password: 'abc'},
      Wrongusername : { username: 'qwe', password: 'as' },
      Wrongpassword: { username: 'xyz', password: 'as@1'}
    }
};
```

I import this in my test case file which is LoginTC.ts and used `using` keyword.

```
using(hardshipTestData.scenarios, (alldata: any, alldesc: any) => {
        it("login with diff data" , () => {
            username.sendKeys(alldata.username);   
            password.sendKeys(alldata.password);
```

by this code, all data will be picked from Data.ts file but I want to pick only one data set like

```
CorrectCreds: { username: 'xyz', password: 'abc'}
```

I tried
 `hardshipTestData.scenarios.CorrectCreds` instead of `hardshipTestData.scenarios`
like below but it didn't work for me:

```
using(hardshipTestData.scenarios.CorrectCreds, (alldata: any, alldesc: any) => {
        it("login with diff data" , () => {
            username.sendKeys(alldata.username);   
            password.sendKeys(alldata.password);
```

above code is still picking all data set.

Answer (score 0):

replace & try with this code chunk?

```
 module.exports = { 
        scenarios: { 
            CorrectCreds : { username: 'xyz', password: 'abc'},
            Wrongusername : { username: 'qwe', password: 'as' },
            Wrongpassword : { username: 'xyz', password: 'as@1'}
        }

    }
```

Comment: I tried above code and made changes in 2nd file.like let newd = require('../newData'); 
             using(newd.scenarios.CorrectCreds, (alldata: any, alldesc: any) => , 
                   log.username.sendKeys(alldata.username); but it is not working as expected.